# Getting message for Sitecore CLI-5.2.113 - dotnet sitecore ser pull

Tags: serialization, sitecore-cli

I am doing the Sitecore CLI setup on my local Sitecore site.

I am executing the following command - `dotnet sitecore ser pull`

but I am getting this below message instead of pulling Sitecore items   as,

```
PS C:\Work\Sitecore\Repos> dotnet sitecore ser pull
[roles] Discovered 0 changes after evaluating role list.

[users] Discovered 0 changes after evaluating user list.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: The information in your 'error' above is saying there were no changes discovered to pull down. I don't see an error in the message? Is there part of your error message missing?

Comment: @JasonSt-Cyr Actually, I am getting that message instead of pulling Sitecore items in local repo after executing the command `ser pull`

Comment: Without adding your module config there is no way to determine if you are experiencing a problem or you just haven't configured it correctly. Please add more details and we can reopen the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check the modules section configured inside sitecore.json file is correct.

[image]

It should contain the path of the module file where the configuration for items to be synced are defined. You can specify module file by path or use wild card to include all the file names ending with module.json.

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/create-a-sitecore-content-serialization-module.html

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

The message is showing that your SCS configurations are fine but using those configurations, it is not able to pull anything from source.

There are two parts to it

1. your module.json - Whatever instructions that you have put there (Paths), it will try to look at those paths and try to pull down, currently from your question it is not clear what you have in module.json
2. Second is what @Chirag mentioned, but I feel that configuration should be fine, otherwise it will come up with error that it is not able to find any modules

So sharing those details will help us see what is causing this, It should be straight fwd.

TO me it looks like the path you have mentioned there is nothing to serialize and hence it is not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check two things: module.json and sitecore.json.
In sitecore.json, verify that the correct path to modules is mentioned.
In every folder, check module.json to ensure it is correctly configured, like this:

```
{
  "namespace": "Feature.Test",
  "references": [ "Foundation.*" ],  // This is an optional parameter

  "tags": [ "TemplateRendering" ],   // This is an optional parameter
  "items": {
    "includes": [

      {
        "name": "templates",
        "path": "/sitecore/templates/Feature/Test",
        "allowedPushOperations": "createUpdateAndDelete"
      },

      {
        "name": "renderings",
        "path": "/sitecore/layout/Renderings/Feature/Test",
        "allowedPushOperations": "createUpdateAndDelete"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I suspect your module.json doesn't have entries for your content or whatever you are trying to pull.